# object properties not being cleared

Tags: javascript, object

```
var fields = {date:{type:'date'}};    
var createField = function(field, settings)
{
    var myArgs = {};
    myArgs = fields[field];
    console.log(fields[field]);
    console.log(myArgs);
    console.log(settings);
    if('label' in settings && settings.label) myArgs.label = settings.label;
    // write html
    var html = '';
    myArgs = null;
    return html;
}
var type = 'date';
createField(type, {label:'Date of Birth'});
// log prints no "label" in fields[field] or myArgs, but does in settings
createField(type, {});
// log prints label of "Date of Birth" in both fields[field] and myArgs, but not in settings
```

WTF?

In other words, my function creates a variable from scratch that I don't use anywhere else in my code: `myArgs`. It grabs the args for the field in question from an unchanging declaration at the top of the page. If the `settings` passed to the function have a label, it adds the label to `myArgs` variable. Then before returning to exit the function, I clear `myArgs`.

`label` shows up in `myArgs` every time after the first time it is passed in `settings`, even when it isn't passed by subsequent `settings`.

*EDIT* FTR, `label` should NEVER be printed in `myArgs` or `fields[field]`. It doesn't exist in the latter, and shouldn't exist YET at time of printing in the former.

*** UPDATE ***
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lxqvt6mk/2/

Comment: Thom, your code does not work. Paste a runable code. Use snippet.

Comment: I accidentally typed `and` instead of `&&` when writing out a simplified version of the problem to save you time. I also forgot to define `html` because it was subsumed under my `//write html` comment (again, to save you time). Here's a js fiddle which demonstrates my problem exactly, after making those miniscule two corrections: https://jsfiddle.net/Lxqvt6mk/2/

Answer (score 0):

You assign `fields.date` to `myArgs` and then you modify `myArgs`. Modifying `myArgs` is modifying `fields.date` since `maArgs` refers to it. It's an object. When you assign it to a variable, it's not being copied. You just have two references to the very same object in the memory. You can compare the value of `fields` before and after the invocation of your function.

Next time, please check your code before pasting. The best solution is inserting a runable snippet.

Good luck!